# What set do I have? 2 grey 6x6 circle plates, dark grey, dark red, and dark blue pieces

Tags: sets, set-identification

I found a bag of LEGO pieces without any instructions. I'm trying to find out what set I have.

[image: random bricks]

Comment: *bag of logos* Did you mean a *bag of legos*?

Comment: @A.L Technically all bricks should have the Lego Logo on them so he may have been right... in a way.

Answer (score 8):

THese parts are from [76019-1: Starblaster Showdown](http://brickset.com/sets/76019-1/Starblaster-Showdown) based on

- [Plate 1X4 W. 2 Knobs](http://brickset.com/parts/4631877)
- [Plate 6X6 Round With Tube Snap](http://brickset.com/parts/6015349)
- [Right Plate 2X4 W/Angle](http://brickset.com/parts/4502091)

[image: 76019]